# Find matching values in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, match

I want to find the matching values between two arrays and create a json array setting true if the values matched or false if they didn't. I know, that the values in the secondArray will always match some values from the first array and that it will always be smaller, because the secondArray is created based on the first one.

```
let firstArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
let secondArray = ["Three", "Four"];
let jsonArray = [];
```

I want to create a json array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "One",
    "matched": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Two",
    "matched": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Three",
    "matched": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Four",
    "matched": true
  },
  {
    "name": "Five",
    "matched": false
  }
]
```

Normally, I would do something like this:

```
            firstArray.forEach(firstElement=>{
              secondArray.forEach(secondElement=>{
                  if(firstArray.indexOf(secondElement)>=0){
                      jsonArray.push({'name': secondElement, 'matched': true});
                  }else{
                      jsonArray.push({'name': secondElement, 'matched': false});
                  }
              });
          });
```

But this just creates a json array with duplicated values where the name is the same, but the matched value are falsed and true.

It seems like I'm getting lost in something very simple.

Comment: you have a lot of typos in your code

Comment: you have to merge both array and set matched to false, then ou have to intersect both array and set values from the intersect to matched true in your merged array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the combination of `map` and `includes` helper to achieve that.

```js
let firstArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
let secondArray = ["Three", "Four"];
let jsonArray = [];

jsonArray = firstArray.map(i => {
   return { 'name': i, 'matched': secondArray.includes(i) };
});

console.log(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  let firstArray = ["One", "Two", "Three". "Four", "Five"];
  let secondArray = ["Three", "Four"];
  let jsonArray = [];
  firstArray.forEach(firstElement=>{
        if(secondArray.indexOf(firstElement)>=0){
            jsonArray.push({'name': firstElement, 'matched': true});
        }else{
            jsonArray.push({'name': firstElement, 'matched': false});
        }
 });
```

Hope this code will help you

Comment: @PhilippSander where is typo in my code could you please let me know?

Comment: inexOf should be indexOf

Answer (score 1):

We can use

> Array.prototype.includes()

to check if an element exist or not in an array

```js
let firstArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
let secondArray = ["Three", "Four"];
let jsonArray = [];

firstArray.forEach(val => {
    if (secondArray.includes(val)) {
        jsonArray.push({
            'name': val,
            'matched': true
        })

    } else {
        jsonArray.push({
            'name': val,
            'matched': false
        })
    }

})

console.log(jsonArray);
```

Comment: All the answers are correct, but this one has less code. Approved.

Comment: @sie well in that case you can check my answer ;)

Comment: I did, but now I saw map and return, and it is prettier.

Answer (score 1):

All the other solutions here perform unnecessary computations; their run-time grows with the square of the array length. Try running them with arrays of size 100k+ :-)

The solution you are looking for is quite simple and runs in `O(n)`:

```ts
let firstArray = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"];
let secondArray = ["Three", "Four"];

let map = {};
firstArray.forEach(i => map[i] = false);
secondArray.forEach(i => map[i] === false && (map[i] = true));
let jsonArray = Object.keys(map).map(k => ({ name: k, matched: map[k] }));
```

Answer (score 0):

use th `find` to check element exist

```
firstArray.forEach(secondElement=>{
  let exist = secondArray.find((item) => item === secondElement);
  if(exist){
    jsonArray.push({'name': secondElement, 'matched': true})
  }else{

    jsonArray.push({'name': secondElement, 'matched': false})
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fz6ptq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two way.

`Way1:`
`let array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];`
`let array2 = ['b','d'];`
    `let commonArray = [];`

```
array1.forEach( x => {
    if(array2.indexOf(x) != -1){
      commonArray.push(x);
    }
});`

console.log(commonArray);   //commonArray is the resulting array
```

`Way2: Use intersection of Underscore.js`

```
At first you have to import underscore:  
import * as _ from 'underscore';`  

Then use intersection to calculate common.  
commonArray = _.intersection(array1, array2);

console.log(commonArray);   //commonArray is the resulting array
```